# Positioning Half Circles for All Screen Sizes

Tags: html, css

I'm sorry if this question has already been asked elsewhere.

However, I've got a page I'm building in Leadpages that is due in a couple of hours. It's got these half circles...

[image]

This is the code structure for a half circle...

The HTML is just a straight up plain image.

The CSS is as following:

```
.ring-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 240px;
  top: 2115px;
      }
```

The issue is it’s really hard to get them to look really good on all screen sizes. They change position quite a bit even with a just a tiny browser resize. Which as a result can quickly overlap text over go in a position that does not look natural.

As the width of elements, like the blue block in this photo for example, change, that leaves circle landing in a weird spot. Sometimes overlapping the text.

For example, this would look better at the top...

[image]

Is their a better way to code these in, to better change with the screen sizes? At this moment, I would have to basically make a change as to how far from the top each ring is, with media queries at the moment. Except, that would result in needing to use dozens of media queries. Like one every few pixels practically.

Answer (score 0):

Set that white element with blue squiggles as `position: relative;` if you haven't already, and then set the circles to be children or pseudo-elements (`::before` and `::after`) and keep their position absolute.

> An absolute child (`:before` & `:after` are treated like children as well) will have its position based off of its closest relative ancestor.

Without having all of the markup, it's a bit tough to see what *all* is going on. But using the relative position of the element you want to manipulate will result in FAR fewer media queries, if any.

Take a quick peek at this pen I whipped up and drag the window size around: https://codepen.io/xhynk/full/zYxmENp, and here's the pen link itself if you want to fork it/mess with it: https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/zYxmENp

Comment: Thanks! Would there be any way to do this with an HTML image tag? The client provided me with images. However, it might be easier to build it with CSS like that.

Comment: What part of it is an image? `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements don't work on self closing tags (such as images) so you would have to instead put in sibling elements at the same level as the image

Comment: I'm using image tags just before the closing body tag... <img class="ring-right" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/mNMbzaZ49n3obaxNJ5a6Bk4-EQ6_HnTeimTArbRtWRJYeWCTS6iNU8den5B-qKbi2YADkzV8pSALBU4-Fe_tdg=w1920">

Comment: However,  I forgot to mention... I'm building this page in Leadpages.net. Therefore I'm somewhat limited on how much I can edit.

Comment: The wave pattern background, and the blue background were drag and drop. The circles are something I'm coding into the page.

Comment: However, I did code in the text and button onto the blue background.

Comment: Oh I see. You could set the before/after images to use those images as a `background-image` instead, and remove the border/box-shadow/border-radius type stylings from them. Regardless, your main issue is that in order to reduce unnecessary queries and such, the images should be based inside the wave element, and the wave element should be `position: relative`, so they rings can be manipulated based off of it, instead of the next relative parent (sounds like maybe the <body>?)